# Does a $p$-form eat $p$-vectors or $p$ number of vectors?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

A bilinear form is another term for a $2$-form. So does it eat $2$ distinct vectors or a single $2$-vector?

Comment: Either. Both. After all, you can take $p$ vectors and wedge them together to get a $p$-vector.

Comment: Given that you have used the [tag:exterior-algebra] tag, do you want to talk about *skew* forms?

Comment: Sure. No idea what they are, but I am eager to learn as much as I can.

Comment: bilinear forms, like quadratic forms, are not in an exterior algebra...unless, $b(v,w)=-b(w,v)$... in which case you can write $b$ as a wedge product of one-forms.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I'm confused as to the second part of your comment, I think you mean a linear combination of wedges if you intend that identity to be true for all $v,w$ since $\Lambda^k\left(\Bbb R^n\right)$ is only generated by the $k$-blades.

Comment: @AdamHughes good point. I do mean to say a linear combination of wedge products.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To elaborate on Zhen Lin's comment: either viewpoint of a bilinear form is okay due to the [universal property of the tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property).

Given a vector space $V$ with field of scalars $k$, I've usually seen a bilinear form defined as a bilinear map $B : V \times V \to k$, so a function that eats two vectors as in your first definition.

However, by the universal property of the tensor product, there is a unique linear map $\tilde{B} : V \otimes_k V \to k$ such that $B = \tilde{B} \circ \pi$ where $\pi$ is the map $\pi : V \times V \to V \otimes_k V$, $(v_1, v_2) \mapsto v_1 \otimes v_2$.  So $\tilde{B}$ eats $2$-vectors, as in your second definition.

Since this association $B \leftrightarrow \tilde{B}$ is a bijection, we can in a sense identify $B$ and $\tilde{B}$ and are thus free to think about a bilinear form as a map $V \times V \to k$ or $V \otimes_k V \to k$.  For more on this see section 10.4 of Dummit and Foote.

Answer (score 1):

A bilinear form on a vector space $V$ over a field $\Bbb{F}$ is a bilinear map $B:V\times V\to \Bbb{F}$ which *eats* a pair of vectors to give a scalar according to $(v,w)\mapsto B(v,w)$. This can be generalized.